# Created a join table with a Primary Key column, and two Foreign Key columns, not pulling in data

Tags: sql, join

I created a new table called Expirations that has it's own unique id, with indentity incrementing, as it's primary key. I also want this table to pull in data from two other tables, so I created a column for the InsuranceId and the LicenseId, making both columns foreign keys to connect them to the data (aka ID) from their respective tables (Insurance and License). 
Any idea why my data is not automatically filling in for my Expirations Table? I believe it was created as "many to one" for all of these columns. Not sure if that is correct either, as I want the Expiration table to list all insurance id's and licence id's.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: That's not how creating a foreign key works. You still need to populate your own data.

Answer (score 0):

Foreign keys don't mean that a table gets filled automatically.

Let's say you have a person table and a company table and a company_person table to show which person works in which company. Now you insert three companies and four persons. That doesn't mean that the company_person table gets filled with 3 x 4 = 12 records (i.e. all persons work in all companies). That would make no sense.

Foreign keys merely guarantee that you cannot insert invalid data (i.e. a person that doesn't exist or a company that doesn't exist) into the table in question. You must insert the records yourself.

Comment: So there is no way to take information from one column on a table and information from one column on a second table and make a third new Joined table? That works so when someone adds new data to one of the two tables columns, the joined table gets the info too?

Comment: Of records can be inserted, but not automatically. In my example *you* would insert records into the company_person table, because only *you* know which persons work for which companies. And if in your example *all* insurancies are to be combined with *all* licenses, then it's again *you* who knows that. The DBMS cannot know that.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your expirations table is like a fact table and you want to load data from the dim table which is Insurancetable ( InsuranceId as primarykey) and Licencetable ( Licenceid as PK).

But if you do not have any combination of InsuranceId and licenseId how do you know which insuranceid belongs to which LicenseId.

If your expirations table is empty then you need to first do cross join between the insurancetable and licensetable which is cartesian result but you do not want to do that as it does not make sense in real world.

Hope my explanation helps.